# Determining the Beta Function when Determining the Critical F Value for the F Test

Tags: java, math, statistics

I am using the method outlined [here](http://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/f-statistics-critical-value.php) to determine the critical F value for the F test.  My problem is that [the beta function is an integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).  My x and y are 0.5 and 248 respectively.  I tried to do integration by summation using the following (Java) code.

```
static double BetaFunction(double x, double y){
    double betaFunction=0.0;
    double inc=0.00001, t=0;
    double xM1=x-1, yM1=y-1;

    do{
        t+=inc;         
        betaFunction+=Math.pow(t, xM1)*Math.pow(1.0-t, yM1)*inc;
    } while (t<1.0);

    return betaFunction;
}
```

Unfortunately, the returned value depends very heavily on the value I choose for inc.  As this value is reduced, the run time goes up linearly and the accuracy improves logarithmically.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you'll likely be able to do without a closed form integral solution is using Stirling's approximation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

It is a closed form solution that approaches the real value for "large" n.

`sqrt(2Pi)*x^(x-.5)*y^(y-.5)/(x+y)^(x+y-.5)`

Computing it can at least be done in linear time for `x` and `y`. You'll have to decide for yourself at what ranges to use it and what errors are acceptable to you.

Comment: I tried Stirling's approximation given here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Approximation.  Unfortunately, it was such a high exponent, with y=248, that it overflowed my buffer.  I will try doing it with logarithms.  Thanks OH.

Comment: I was able to implement it with logarithms.  Thanks, OH.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to do an inverse, incomplete beta function. I wrote one of these a long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away. Of course, today I'd just call betaincinv in MATLAB.

You simply DON'T want to do it by numerical integration with a small step size. Certainly not as a rectangle rule integration, as you have here. Note that the beta has a somewhat nasty shape for parameters like this. (Ok, somewhat nasty is a nice way to say it. It really is just plain nasty.)

Abramowitz & Stegun has a few approximations that will help as I recall. Then you could refine the result using a quick step with Newton's method. This works nicely, since the derivative of an integral is so easily evaluated.